# "Service cron status" command does not give back the status of cron in the ubuntu docker container

Tags: linux, cron, docker

I use ubuntu:latest image, cron is already installed, because my cron job doesn't run at all. I want to check if the cron deamon is running in my docker container.

so I type in

```
service cron status
```

results in:

```
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8) utility, e.g. service cron status
Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart job, you may also use the status(8) utility, e.g. status cron
```

gives me no result of the status of cron, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

The service name is wrong. Here is the fix with `crond`

```
service crond status
```